# Results do not match between manually computed PSD values and those from MATLAB pwelch function

Tags: matlab, dft, power-spectral-density

The power spectral density (PSD) of the given input signal $x[n]$ is computed as follows:

```
close all;clear;clc

n = 8;
F = dftmtx(n);
invF = 1/n*F';

rng default
x = randn(100*n,1);

xx = buffer(x,n,n-1);
xx = xx(:, n:end);

XX = fft(xx, n);

phixx = mean(XX.*conj(XX),2)/n;
phixx = phixx.';
```

Then, the `phixx` is

```
phixx = 
   1.0837    1.1155    0.8099    0.9498    1.0470    0.9498    0.8099    1.1155
```

If the MATLAB built-in function `pwelch` is used to compute the PSD, then the results are quite different from what is shown above:

```
pp = pwelch(x, ones(n,1), n-1, n)'

   0.1725    0.3551    0.2578    0.3023    0.1666
```

As it is one side, so the length is only `n/2+1`, but I expected the values to be identical to each other.

Was the way how `pwelch` was used wrong?

Please let me know if there should be more detailed information.

**update**

I just found out that the results are identical except for a $\pi$ or $2\pi$ difference between them, i.e.,

```
(phixx(1:n/2+1)./pp)/pi

ans =

    2.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    2.0000
```

There seems a constant involved in computing `pwelch`.

Then, I am wondering which one should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `pwelch()` can return a one sided (default) or two sided spectrum. For one sided, the energy of negative frequency is added to the symmetric positive ones.
2. `pwelch()` returns a spectral density in something like $W/Hz$ which is actually dependent on the sample rate. By default `pwelch()` assumes a sample rate of $2\pi$.

Try

```
pp = pwelch(x, ones(n,1), n-1, n,1,'twosided')';
```

`pwelch()` is fairly complicated so it's typically not a bad idea to read through the entire documentation and understand all the different options before using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, the 'twosided' variable works and now it seems that the results coincide. This time could be a good chance to read through the entire `doc pwelch`.  But in regard to the first bullet point in your answer, if the energy of negative frequency is added to the symmetric positive ones, then I expect the values of `(phixx(1:n/2+1)./pp)/pi` should be somehow 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0. But the actual values are the other way around.

Comment: Yes if you use "onsided", no if you use "twosided". Note that twosided returns and 8 element vector and onesided a 5-element one. You want to maintain Perceval's theorem $\sum P(k) = \sum x[n]^2$